# Why can we drop the Omega term in Euler's expression of AC signal?

Tags: ac

I know that for an AC signal like $$V=V_p\cos(\omega t+ \phi)$$ we can simplify it to $$Re(V_p e^{j(\omega t+\phi)})$$ But why can we further simplify it by dropping the Omega term  $$Re(V_p e^{j\phi})$$?

Comment: Probably because \$j \omega t \$ equals 0 somehow.

Comment: Why do you think that you "can further simplify"? Who told you this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should give the book or docs where the equations come. Maybe it's just for convenient. Because the results of signals addition/subtraction with same frequency also have the same frequency with themselves.

Below is another version, and i think this version is more clear.

In Fundamentals of Electric Circuits, 5th by Sdiku, Matthew, Page. 378

$$
v(t)=V_{m}cos(\omega t+\phi)=Re(V_{m}e^{j(\omega t + \phi)})
$$

Thus

$$
v(t)= Re(\dot{V}e^{j \omega t})
$$

where

$$
\dot{V}=V_{m}e^{j\phi}=V_{m} \angle \phi
$$

\$\dot{V}\$ is thus the ***phasor representation*** of the sinusoid \$v(t)\$.

Note: for clarity, i put one dot on top of \$V\$.

---

In your equations, apparently, the second and the third equation can't be equal, in your second equation, \$V_{p}\$ should be a scalar, and in your third equation \$V_{p}\$ should be a vector.